# Oracle RDS Logminer ORA-01291 Missing Log File?

Tags: oracle, logging, amazon-rds, logminer

I have an Oracle RDS database I manage, and I need to be able to pull changes from the database for replication to another system. Once connect to the database, below is the commands I run.

```
EXEC rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.create_directory(p_directory_name => 'logminerlogs');
set heading off;
set echo off;
set space 0;
set pagesize 0;
set linesize 10000;
set termout off;
set trimout on;
SET TRIMSPOOL ON;
set feedback off;
set newpage NONE;
set define on;
exec dbms_stats.gather_dictionary_stats;
EXEC rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.alter_supplemental_logging('ADD','PRIMARY KEY');
EXEC rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.alter_supplemental_logging('ADD','UNIQUE');
BEGIN
dbms_logmnr.add_logfile(
logfilename=> 'rdsdbdata/db/ORCL_A/arch?redolog-99999-9-9999999999.arc');
*** REPEAT for all redo logs ***
END
/
EXECUTE dbms_logmnr.start_logmnr(STARTTIME=>SYSDATE-1,ENDDATE=>SYSDATE,OPTIONS=>DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_REDO_LOGS+DBMS_LOGMNR.COMMITTED_DATA_ONLY+DBMS_LOGMNR.PRINT_PRETTY_SQL);
```

Doing all of that gives me the error

```
ORA-01291: missing log file
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR", line 72
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I get all of the 'arc' files by querying

```
SELECT name FROM v$archived_log WHERE first_time > SYSDATE-1 and first_time < systdate ORDER BY 1;
```

I ran all of these scripts once and I was able to query `v$logmnr_contents` and get the results I wanted.  When I opened another SQLPlus window and ran all of the scripts again, I get the error of Missing Log File mentioned above.

I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong here.  I have also tried

```
DBMS_LOGMNR_D.BUILD(dictionary_filename=>'lgmnrdict.ora',dictionary_location=>'LOGMNRLOGS');
```

where `LOGMNRLOGS` is a dictionary folder I created previously, and then instead of the redologs when calling `add_logfile` I point to the 4 onlinelogs *.log files* that exist on the database and then run command

```
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(dictfilename=>'/rdsdbdata/userdirs/o1/logmnrdict.ora');
```

This will start Logminer, but when I make any changes and commit to the database, when I query `v$logmnr_contents` those changes are not being returned.

I realize I might be rambling at this point, but I feel like I am very close to the solution; I'm just missing something.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The 19c error manual says to look at v$logmnr_logs to see which logs are missing, for what that is worth.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that for each add_logfile command, I was setting options for dbms_logmnr.new for each rather than for the first and all remaining redologs using dbms_logmnr.addfile.